# Bugzilla SMTP authentication

Tags: smtp, bugzilla, smtp-auth

I've installed bugzilla in my local machine (Windows 7) and its working good. But when I try to create a new account it says

> There was an error sending mail from `it@gmail.com` to `ra@gmail.com`:
>   Could't set FROM:
>   530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   Learn more at at `C:/Perl/site/lib/Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm` line 49.

What changes shall I do in `TLS.pm`?

I've even configured the parameter>Email section in bugzilla:

> mail_delivery_method = `SMTP::TLS`,
>   mailfrom = `it@gmail.com`,
>   smtpserver = `smtp.gmail.com:587`,
>   smtp_username = my gmail username,
>   smtp_password = my gmail password,

The `TLS.pm` file line 49 says: `$SMTP->mail($from);`

Have I left anything else to work SMTP?

Comment: What version of Bugzilla is this?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have following in `Mailer.pm`. Just open the file and edit it. Note that  the field name is **'User'** not **'username'**.  To avoid compatibility issues, if any, keep both.

```
User => Bugzilla->params->{"smtp_username"},  
Password => Bugzilla->params->{"smtp_password"},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. In my case I messed up with `password` vs `Password` attribute. I found a blog mentioned `password`, all small letters. And it didnt work. But when I capitalized the `p` as mentioned by Dinesh above, it worked. So check if the hash keys are properly written.