# Bugzilla Gmail SMTP failed to authenticate

Tags: authentication, smtp, bugzilla, gmail-imap

I have a bugzilla 4.4.2 installation. I want to use the gmail smtp service to send email from my application. I have applied these blogs

- http://www.dawood.in/bugzilla-alerts-using-gmail/
- http://prasadlinuxblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/975/

Applied the patches mentioned there. I configured the mta parameters in Bugzilla admin section with my gmail user name and password. Note that, I am not using two step verification in google account. So after all these, the application fails with an Authentication Error. It says the following message

> There was an error sending mail from 'myemailaddress@gmail.com' to 'receiver@gmail.com': Could't set FROM: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at at lib/Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm line 49

Cant really figure out whats going wrong here. I found one similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533805/3692283 but I am already following the solution mentioned there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bugzilla SMTP authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429314/bugzilla-smtp-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the email entered at the SMTP user is still valid. If the password is no longer valid, then it cannot be chosen as the SMTP user name.

The SMTP password is the email's password.